# how to get transaction id in stripe payment gateway

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using stripe payment gateway in php. Everything is working. But not showing transaction id after successful payment. How to get transaction id?

```
if(isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
{
$amount_cents = str_replace(".","","1.00");  // Chargeble amount
$invoiceid = "14526321";                      // Invoice ID
$description = "Invoice #" . $invoiceid . " - " . $invoiceid;

try {

    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                    "amount" => $amount_cents,
                    "currency" => "usd",
                    "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                    "description" => $description)
    );
    // Payment has succeeded, no exceptions were thrown or otherwise caught

    $result = "success";

} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {

    $error = $e->getMessage();
    $result = "declined";

} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
    $result = "declined";
} catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
    $result = "declined";
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
    $result = "declined";
} catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
    $result = "declined";
} catch (Exception $e) {


}

        // Charge the Customer instead of the card


if($result=="success") {
    $response = "<div class='col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 text-success'>Your Payment has been processed successfully.</div>";
} else{
    $response = "<div class='text-danger'>Stripe Payment Status : \".$result.</div>";
}
}
?>
```

Above code is for after form submit.

Comment: Can you clarify which transaction ID you're expecting? Are you referring to the ID of the charge? the underlying balance transaction? $charge->id should have the ID of the charge, in this case.

Comment: Also flagging that the `Stripe_Charge` approach dates from the 1.X version of stripe-php which was deprecated well over 5 years ago and you should really look into upgrading your system to use the latest version of stripe-php

Answer (score -1):

You are getting your API response in the variable `$charge`. Comment out `$result = s"success";` and `write echo($charge);`. You will see the response. In the response, the `'balance_transaction'` value that starts with `'tx_'` is the transaction id. Do save it to your database for further use.

Check the stripe API docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object